# jQuery simple checkbox to hide and show divs (product filtering)

Tags: jquery, html, custom-data-attribute

I am using jQuery to filter product items on a page (hide and display DIVs) I am using filter as a replacement since PHP $_GET is a bit old fashion we're trying to do this via jQuery. I using filter() and data attribute.

How can I turn off the current selection of checkboxes except the existing item?
How can I hide the items based off selection and unhide when not?

## HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" id="drama" onClick="filterCategory(this.value)" value="drama" /> Drama<br />
<input type="checkbox" id="romance" onClick="filterCategory(this.value)" value="" /> Romance<br />
<input type="checkbox" id="horror" onClick="filterCategory(this.value)" value="horror" /> Horror<br />

<!--------------------->
<div class="products">
    <div class="productItem" data-price="250" data-category="horror">
        Scary Book
        <div class="productItemPrice"><span>&pound;250</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="productItem" data-price="150" data-category="drama">
        Drama Poems
        <div class="productItemPrice"><span>&pound;150</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="productItem" data-price="250" data-category="romance">
        Love Story
        <div class="productItemPrice"><span>&pound;250</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="productItem" data-price="241" data-category="horror">
        Creep Book
        <div class="productItemPrice"><span>&pound;241</span></div>
    </div>
</div>
<!--------------------->
```

## jQUERY

```
function filterCategory(id) {
    var pid=$(".productItem"); // Which product is it
    var checkid=$('#'+id); // The name of the checkbox form
    var cid=$(pid).data("category"); // The value of the checkbox form
    if ($(checkid).is(':checked')){
        $(pid).hide().filter(function () {var catId=$(this).data("category");return catId;}).show();
    } else {
        $(pid).show().filter(function () {var catId=$(this).data("category");return catId;}).show();
    }
}
```

## CSS

```
.productItem{float:left;padding:5px;margin:5px;border:1px solid #eaeaea}
body{font-family:verdana}
```

## JSFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/RyZy8/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try using something like this instead,

Firstly remove the `onclick` attribute on the checkboxes - use jQuery to bind the `click` event :

```
// bind to click
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
    // any checked
    if ($('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length > 0) {
        // hide all
        $('.products >div').hide();
        // loop checked and display relavent div
        $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function() {
            $('.products >div[data-category=' + this.id + ']').show();
        });
    } else {
        // none checked - show all
        $('.products >div').show();
    }
});​
```

[Working example here](http://jsfiddle.net/manseuk/RyZy8/3/)

Comment: But this does not restore the list. So clicking horror which show horror and click it again will show the list again.

Comment: @TheBlackBenzKid added if statement