# jQuery product filtering on multiple categories using checkboxes

Tags: jquery, filter, hide, show

This question is a further development of this question:

[jQuery simple checkbox to hide and show divs (product filtering)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12563152/jquery-simple-checkbox-to-hide-and-show-divs-product-filtering) which was answered excellently by [ManseUK](https://stackoverflow.com/users/572939/manseuk)

ManseUK's solution enabled product filtering by a single category, specifically genre but for my current project I need to sort by 2 categories: colour and size. By modifying ManseUK's solution I nearly have it working but it fails when I have two filters selected - in this example selecting 'cyan' and 'xl' should only show the xl cyan but instead it shows both cyans instead of just the xl cyan. The code I'm using is as follows:

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="cyan" value="cyan" /> Cyan<br />
<input type="checkbox" id="magenta" value="magenta" /> Magenta<br />
<input type="checkbox" id="black" value="black" /> Black<br />
<input type="checkbox" id="xl" value="xl" /> XL<br />

<!--------------------->
<div class="products">
    <div class="productItem" data-price="250" data-category="cyan">
        Cyan Ink
        <div class="productItemPrice"><span>&pound;250</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="productItem" data-price="150" data-category="magenta">
        Magenta Ink
        <div class="productItemPrice"><span>&pound;150</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="productItem" data-price="250" data-category="black">
        Black Ink        <div class="productItemPrice"><span>&pound;250</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="productItem" data-price="241" data-category="cyan" data-size="xl">
        XL Cyan Ink
        <div class="productItemPrice"><span>&pound;241</span></div>
    </div>
</div>
<!--------------------->​
```

CSS:

```
.productItem{float:left;padding:5px;margin:5px;border:1px solid #eaeaea}
body{font-family:verdana}
```

JS:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
    if ($('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length > 0) {
        $('.products >div').hide();
        $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function() {
            $('.products >div[data-category=' + this.id + ']').show();
            $('.products >div[data-size=' + this.id + ']').show();
        });
    } else {
        $('.products >div').show();
    }
});​
```

[JSFIDDLE of the above code](http://jsfiddle.net/NGy7D/)

I can see that the js is performing a logical OR on which divs to show - how can I make this an AND?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Made some changes to the code ..

- Cached the variables.
- You are looping over all the checkboxes and assigning the id's to
  it. You need to Query the size separately as it's a different
  entity..
- I am looping only the checkboxes that is not size .. All colors
- Then checking is Size is also check for each color...

**FULL CODE**

```
 $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
    // Cache These Variables
    var $checked = $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked');
    var $productsDiv = $('.products > div');
    var $sizeCheckBox = $('input[type="checkbox"][value="xl"]');

    if ($checked.length > 0) {
        $productsDiv.hide();
        // If only XL Checkbox is Checked
        if ($checked.length == 1 && $sizeCheckBox.is(':checked')) {
              $('.products > div[data-size=' + $sizeCheckBox.attr('id') + ']')
                 .show();
        } 
        // If Others are also Checked
        else {
            // All Checkboxes and Not Size Checkbox
            $checked.not($sizeCheckBox).each(function() {
                var dataSize = '';
                if ($sizeCheckBox.is(':checked')) {
                    dataSize = '[data-size=' + $sizeCheckBox.attr('id') + ']';
                }
                $('.products >div[data-category=' + this.id + ']' 
                             + dataSize).show();
            });
        }
    } else {
        $productsDiv.show();
    }
});​
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/NGy7D/3/)**

Comment: @AndyPlatt .. I made some changes to the post .. have a look at it

Comment: That's really close - but I need it to show the 'Cyan XL' if just the XL is checked, is that possible? (Thanks for your help with this - you're a lifesaver)

Comment: @AndyPlatt .. you need to add once more check condition .. Added that .. Check edited post

Comment: @AndyPlatt .. Glad to have helped :)